# Cannot access an option in select dropdown in selenium with python- "Element is not currently visible"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, select

I'm trying to fill the form in this page https://blend.co.il/register/ and i trying to automate the first dropdown select by using this line:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select-year")).select_by_visible_text("1992")
```

and i got this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: 
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0):

Looks text is not directly available in option.. use select by value like select.select_by_value("2000")